# What built in code snippets does TypeScript have in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

The only built in code snippet that I know in TypeScript is `ctor` which generates a constructor method. What are the other TypeScript code snippets that are available in VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v1.47.0 they support the following:

```
Constructor / prefix: ctor
Class Definition / prefix: class
Public Method Definition / prefix : public method
Private Method Definition / prefix : private method
Import external Module / prefix: import statement
Property getter / prefix : get
Property setter / prefix: set
Log to the console / prefix: log
Log warning / prefix: warn
Log error / prefix: error
Define a full property / prefix: prop
Triple-slash reference / prefix: ref
Throw exception / prefix: throw
For loop / prefix: for
For-Each Loop using => / prefix: foreach =>
For-In Loop / prefix: forin
For-Of Loop / prefix: forof
Function Statement / prefix: function
If Statement / prefix: if
If-Else Statement / prefix: ifelse
New Statement / prefix: new
Switch Statement / prefix: switch
While Statement / prefix: while
Do-While Statement / prefix: dowhile
Try-Catch Statement / prefix: trycatch
Set Timeout Function / prefix: settimeout
Region Start / prefix: #region
Region End / prefix: #endregion
```

Additionally, they support jsDoc (`"typescript.suggest.completeJSDocs": true`) and directive comment completions

---

Resources: [ [typescript snippets](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/d5e12a12ddcdbffa565ea36aec17d94df7c9f3d9/extensions/typescript-basics/snippets/typescript.code-snippets) | [jsDoc completions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/d5e12a12ddcdbffa565ea36aec17d94df7c9f3d9/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/features/jsDocCompletions.ts) | [directive comments completions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/d5e12a12ddcdbffa565ea36aec17d94df7c9f3d9/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/features/directiveCommentCompletions.ts) ]